# symfony2 form creator based on annotations

Tags: php, forms, symfony, annotations

I'm working on mechanism that will allow me create forms automatically from class annotations. 
For example there is a class called "News" with some custom annotations.

```
/**
 * @Admin\Form(name="news")
 */
class News
{
    /**
     *
     * @Admin\Field(name="title", type="text")
     */
    private $title;

}
```

My goal is to write mechanism that will check if exists class with "Form" annotation and create form based on this class fields.

Where should I put this mechanism? First I was thinking about owerwritting FormFactory but I believe there is a better place for such thing, maybe Extension?

Answer (score 3):

There already is a bundle that does what you're asking for: http://knpbundles.com/FlintLabs/FormMetadataBundle

However, if you'd like to create it yourself, you should create a bundle and within it create a custom annotation driver based on the doctrine2 specs (as Symfony uses Doctrine for reading annotations)

Comment: Thanks a lot! But this is not exactly what I'm asking :P I know that I need to create drivers (annotation, ymal, xml etd) but my question is about how to inject this mechanism to symfony form without overwriting it. 
In FormMetadataBundle there is a service that use symfony form factory and I'm not sure that this is the best way.

Comment: Ah! I misunderstood. I'm not sure what better options are out there, but good luck in finding out.

Answer (score 0):

In Symfony2, you can add functionality to existing form fields through the use of ["Form Type Extensions"](http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/cookbook/form/create_form_type_extension.html).

To apply your extension to all field types, set the return value of the `getExtendedType()` method to "form", i.e:

```
public function getExtendedType()
{
    return 'form';
}
```

I haven't figured out how to fetch the annotations from the form extension yet.